# Stitches on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles, medicine, health-safety-shmira

If someone cut their finger (lo aleinu!) on Shabbos in a way that wasn't going to threaten them however is a fairly deep cut may they get stitches put in by a non-Jew on Shabbos? Theoretically they could simply put on a bandage and wait until after Shabbos. Even though they might have a lot of pain from this, not necessarily would the pain be relieved from the stitches. As well with the bandage perhaps there is not a concern for bacteria getting in now.

The shailo could be broken down by first determining if this is a problem "tefira" (sewing -- which is normally ossur on Shabbos) by a person? If it is, perhaps since it won't be there for a long time it could be there is also a heter.

Keep in mind this is all being done with a goy, the question is is this a malacha at all in regards to putting stitches on a person. Perhaps it is but only a d'rabbanan and would have more room to allow this by using a non-Jew.

Comment: If it involves going to the emergency room, DO. LIKE. TUESDAY.

Answer (score 3):

If an injury is serious enough to require stitches, it's serious enough to require them on Shabbath.

Now, how seriously one needs to *personally* violate Shabbath (driving, calling an ambulance, signing forms, etc.) to see a doctor to perform the procedure may depend on the severity and one's ability to circumvent Shabbath violations in the course of pursuing medical treatment.

But if it's just a question of having a non-Jew stitch a cut, again, any cut requiring stitches is severe enough to permit.

There are other considerations besides pain or even blood-loss, by the way, such as risk of infection, and in the case of a finger (and other extremities) nerve damage, to name just two of many. A small bandage might not be able to prevent infection if the cut is severe.

For practical guidance, CYLOR and CYLMD.

Source: My LOR and LMD.

Comment: Even a cut on ones finger that perhaps only needs a few stitches?

Comment: @Yehoshua, most cuts don't require stitches at all. If one does, however, that is a severe enough cut to seek medical attention even on Shabbath.

Answer (score 0):

R Yisroel Pinchos Bodner ([Halachos of refuah on Shabbos](https://www.feldheim.com/halachos-of-refuah-on-shabbos), pp. 335-37) answers your question as follows

According to many Poskim, sewing/suturing a wound on Shabbos is a possible violation of a Torah prohibition (*tefira*). Therefore

> Accordingly, one's wound **may not be sutured by a Jewish doctor unless
> it is a Life-Threatening situation** (for example, if waiting until
> after Shabbos will pose a risk of a possible Life-Threatening
> infection).
>
> 1. No Risk of Life-Threatening Infection
>
> In most situations, if a wound is only moderately deep (i.e., it does
> not penetrate beyond the full thickness of skin into the fatty tissue
> or muscle tissue), and if it is properly cleaned and bandaged, it is
> not an emergency to have the wound sutured immediately. One can delay
> suturing until after Shabbos without causing any ill effect.
>
> 2. Possible Risk of Life-Threatening Infection
>
> **However, if the wound is deep** (i.e., it penetrates beyond the full
> thickness of skin into the fatty tissue or muscle tissue), **it should
> be considered a medical emergency**. In such cases, waiting until after
> Shabbos will pose a risk of infection which could possibly become
> Life-Threatening.
>
> There are also cases, when the wound has not penetrated the full
> thickness of the skin, but — due to the nature of the wound or due to
> the circumstances — a doctor may feel that a delay could pose a risk of
> Life-Threatening infection. In such cases of infection risk, if a
> non-Jewish doctor is not available, the suturing may be performed on
> Shabbos by a Jewish doctor.
>
> **If a wound appears to be gaping open, and one does not know if it
> poses an infection risk, he should treat it as a potentially
> Life-Threatening condition, and not hesitate because of Shabbos**
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE: If the bleeding is pulsating or does not stop within
> ten minutes, it is possible that an artery has been cut and the victim
> will need emergency medical assistance. One should not hesitate at all
> because of Shabbos.
>
> 3. To Save Victim from an Unsightly Scar
>
> According to some Poskim, if stitches are needed to save a victim from
> having an unsightly scar, and it cannot wait until after Shabbos, the
> wound may be sutured by a non-Jewish doctor.